# How do I print this list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am supposed to print this list of lists nicely without the brackets, but I'm struggeling a bit. I dont get each list on one line. What should I do?

```
python
big_numbers = [
        ["Million",    "10^6 ", "10^6 "],
        ["Milliard",   "     ", "10^9 "],
        ["Billion",    "10^9 ", "10^12"],
        ["Billiard",   "     ", "10^15"],
        ["Trillion",   "10^12", "10^18"],
        ["Quadrillion","10^15", "10^24"],
        ["Quintillion","10^18", "10^30"],
        ["Sextillion", "10^21", "10^36"] ]

print('%7s %7s %7s' %('Number', 'long', 'short'))
for i in range(len(big_numbers)):
    for j in range (len(big_numbers[i])):
        print(big_numbers[i][j], end='')
```

Comment: You should try removing the `end=''` from the print so that there will be the default new-line added to the end of the `print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work just fine for you. And will do what you want.

```
bigNumbers = [
        ["Million ",    "10^6", "10^6"],
        ["Milliard",   "", "10^9"],
        ["Billion ",    "10^9", "10^12"],
        ["Billiard",   "", "10^15"],
        ["Trillion",   "10^12", "10^18"],
        ["Quadrillion","10^15", "10^24"],
        ["Quintillion","10^18", "10^30"],
        ["Sextillion", "10^21", "10^36"]]

print("{:12} {:6} {:6}".format('Number', 'Long', 'Short'))
for i in bigNumbers:
    print("{:12} {:6} {:6}".format(*i))
```

> Here's how the output would look like

```
Number           Long        Short
Million          10^6        10^6
Milliard                     10^9
Billion          10^9        10^12
Billiard                     10^15
Trillion         10^12       10^18
Quadrillion      10^15       10^24
Quintillion      10^18       10^30
Sextillion       10^21       10^36
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Instead of repeating yourself you can use `fmt = "{:12} {:6} {:6}".format` then use `fmt(*i)` See [here](https://repl.it/repls/PettyDistantConference)

Comment: Why `{:12} {:6} {:6}`?

Comment: @Barb The first column will contain 12 rows. if there are less columns in data then it is made 12 by adding spaces. For example "Million" would be replaced  by the word "Million      " with 6 spaces at the end of "Million". A total of 12 characters

Comment: @Barb Biggest word in the first column is 11 characters (add one for the space) and the short columns max at 5 characters (add one for space). Anything less and you get wonky formatting

Comment: ah I see. Can it not be put into 1 line of code with dictionary comprehension? a variation of `new_numbers = {i: k, v for i, k, v in big numbers print({} {} {}.format(i, k, v))}`

Comment: This would mess up the formatting.I think you should try your code in an editor. Then you'll understand. Trying out is the best way to learn

Comment: And the correct version of your code would be `new_numbers = {(i, k, v) for i, k, v in bigNumbers}`

Answer (score 1):

- unpack list using `*`

```
for l in big_numbers:
    print(*l) # you can specify sep='' here for formating.
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But how do I get the numbers on line with each other?

Answer (score 1):

A mixture of unpacking and specifying column width can give you some nice looking formatting.

```
for number in big_numbers:
    print('{:12} {:6} {:6}'.format(*number))
```

This results in:

```
Million      10^6   10^6 
Milliard            10^9
Billion      10^9   10^12
.....
```

Comment: Thank you so much!